# tinylog2 does not create log file

Tags: java, logging, error-handling, tinylog

I am using tinylog2 to log in my application.

When I set the config to log to console it works fine. On the other hand, when I change writer to value "file" It is not working and I don't know why. I tried to search, but it seems that the problem is somehow related to my machine/app or something like that. For others logging to file works fine at least according to comments etc.

I attach my config:

```
writer = file
writer.file  = log.txt
writer.format = {date: HH:mm:ss.SSS} {tag} {level}: {message}
writer.level = debug
writer.charset  = Windows-1250
```

My usage:

```
Logger.debug("something");
```

Thank you to anybody for help.

Comment: Could you try to set an absolute path to the log file? tinylog supports relative and absolute paths to log files. However, for testing, if tinylog really doesn't output anything, it could help.

Comment: On my system, your configuration does work and creates log.txt.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I will try to investigate what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a terrible mistake. I searched in incorrect folder. At least I verified that relative path works fine.